# How to group rows with duplicate value in 1 column and different value in another column without removing/dropping other duplicated rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with about 12K+ rows and 16 columns. Some of the rows are duplicates, which is fine, but I want to group those who are duplicated at 1 column, but different at this 1 specific column. For a simple example, refer below :

```
ID    Plate_Number          
A     SWD1314
A     SKT5721
B     SKT1419
B     SKT1419
C     MNJ1009
C     MNJ1009
```

Now, my desired output is to get the customer with ID A and not B. Basically, I want to see a customer with

I want the result to be like this :
DF only for customer A

```
ID    Plate_Number          
A     SWD1314
A     SKT5721
```

And DF only for customer B and C :

```
ID    Plate_Number 
B     SKT1419
B     SKT1419
C     MNJ1009
C     MNJ1009
```

I have tried using groupBy :

```
df.groupby(['ID'])
```

I also tried :

```
mask = df.duplicated(subset=['ID'], keep=False)
df[mask]
```

But both of them will also give customer B and C inside the list. I want to get duplicate ID with a different plate_number. There must be a way that I am not aware of to get only customer A, not B and C. Thank you.

Edit : If possible, I don't want to remove customer B and C since they are still relevant, it's just that Customer A belongs to another group, while customer B and C belong in another.

Edit : Added 1 more expected outcome, which is a DF for customer B and C.

Comment: Use `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID', 'Plate_Number'], keep=False)`

Comment: Maybe also add `sort_values('ID')` to be sure to get `A` and not `B` @jezrael

Comment: @Erfan - I think not necessary. Because removed all dupes.

Comment: @jezrael If possible, I don't want to remove the other duplicated rows. More like I want to put customer A into another DF since customer B and C are still relevant in another group.

Comment: @Lutfi - Can you add expected ouput if dont need remove `customer B and C` ?

Comment: @jezrael I have added another expected outcome, which is 2 separated dataframe. One DF is only for customer A and another DF with only customers B and C. Sorry if I keep editing the questions and how I ask the question. English is not my main language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative with `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID', 'Plate_Number'], keep=False)
```

Output:

```
  ID Plate_Number
0  A      SWD1314
1  A      SKT5721
```

Comment: good, then rather close like dupe.

Comment: @jezrael more or less the same, of course, just gets rid of the `mask` if it's not needed for anything else

Comment: yes, it is reason why removed answer.

Comment: @jezrael cool, makes sense

Comment: @perl I have edited the question. I don't want to remove the other duplicated rows. More like I want to put customer A into another DF since customer B and C are still relevant in another group.

Comment: @Lutfi `df.drop_duplicates(...` doesn't make changes in-place, but only returns a new dataframe. If you make `df1 = df.drop_duplicates(...` you will have your `df` unchanged, and `df1` created with only non-duplicated rows